# How to target correct child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add the whole `iframe` to an array once I click on their respective ***add btn***

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2tM1LFFxeKg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    <div class="caption">
       <p>Duration: 
         <span class="video-time">4:20</span>
       </p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video">
         <strong>ADD</strong>
       </button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2tM1LFFxeKg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
      </div>
    <div class="caption">
       <p>Duration: 
         <span class="video-time">4:20</span>
       </p>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video">
          <strong>ADD</strong>
       </button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function () {
  var urls = [];
  $('.btn_video').each(function () {
     urls.push($(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".thumbnail").closest(".embed-responsive").html());
  });
  var str = '';
  urls.forEach(function (url) {
    str += url;
  });
  $('#usp-custom-5').val(str);
});
```

What I am having printed out is:

> undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined

Comment: The DOM navigation you've got is wrong; you can use `.closest()` to find the ".col-sm-4" container and then `.find()` to get to the `<iframe>`. Even if you do that, however, the browser will not allow you access to the `<iframe>` contents because it's from a domain different than yours.

Comment: if I use urls.push($(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".thumbnail").html()); I get all the divs with their iframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your *click listener* you don't need the `each()` function and you can select the *iframe html* using this:

```
$(this).closest(".thumbnail").find(".embed-responsive")
```

See demo below:

```js
var urls = [];
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
  urls.push($(this).closest(".thumbnail").find(".embed-responsive").html());
  $('#usp-custom-5').text(urls.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2tM1LFFxeKg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Duration:
        <span class="video-time">4:20</span>
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video">
        <strong>ADD</strong>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2tM1LFFxeKg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Duration:
        <span class="video-time">4:20</span>
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video">
        <strong>ADD</strong>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="usp-custom-5"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function () {
  var urls = [];
  $('.btn_video').each(function () {
      urls.push($(this).closest(".thumbnail").find(".embed-responsive").html());
  });

  var str = '';
  urls.forEach(function (url) {
         str += url;
  });
  $('#usp-custom-5').val(str);
});
```

Comment: this is adding all the iframes

Comment: @rob.m that's what your own code attempts to do; otherwise why the `.each()` loop?

Comment: if you want to collect all iframes in one click, you need each loop, otherwise if you need just clicked div's iframe, dont need.